# Functional derivative in the integral domain

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the (fix) spatial domain $\Omega$ and the functional $F(x)$ as

$$F(x)=\int_{\Omega}f(x)d\Omega$$

where  $x\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x)$ is a smooth function. The first variational derivative with respect to $x$ is given by

$$\frac{\delta F(x)}{\delta x}=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$$

Now consider that the domain is time varying according to a variable $\eta(t)$, i.e., $\Omega=\Omega(\eta(t))$ and

$$F(x,\eta)=\int_{\Omega(\eta)}f(x)d\Omega(\eta)$$

Then, how can we obtain the first variational derivative with respect to $\eta$?, i.e., $\frac{\delta F(x,\eta)}{\delta \eta}=?$

I try to solve it and obtain

$$\frac{\delta F(x,\eta)}{\delta\eta}=f(x)\frac{\partial \Omega(\eta)}{\partial \eta}$$

But I don't sure about it.

Comment: What is the $\delta$ notation?

Comment: It is unclear how $F$ is defined. if $x$ is the variable to be integrated, then $\int_\Omega f(x) d\Omega$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: When using the $\delta$ notation for the *functional derivative*, do you mean the *first variation* of $F$? Or are you simply trying to differentiate $F$ with respect to $x$? If the latter, you need to better define $F$, since as @ArcticChar has pointed out, your function is not well defined.

Once you better define your function, you should look at Reynold's Transport Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem), it helps deal with variable domains like you suggest.

Comment: Zeta-Squared, with the $\delta$ notation, I refer to the variational derivative.

Comment: @Arctic Char, $x\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ is a state variable defined in $\Omega$

Comment: @ValidNinja , with the $\delta$ notation I refer to the variational derivative.  In this case, $F$ is a functional with respect to a variable $x$ in $\Omega$. For example, $x$ represents the state variable of a dynamic system in a domain $\Omega$ and $F$ describes the total energy stored by the system.  The time varying domain is tipical in applications as the fluid-structure interaction, where the fluid domain varies accoding the state variables of the structure.

Comment: It seems that when $\Omega(\eta(t))$, $x$ has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: @ArcticChar, Yes,  you can consider $x$ as the state variable of a dynamical system, i.e., $x=x(\zeta,t)$ where $\zeta\in\Omega$ denotes the spatial variables. $x$ varies accoding a function $$ \dot{x}=g(x), \forall \zeta\in\Omega$$